# Silverlight on Xbox

Tags: silverlight, xbox360

I have an application which works fin in Wp7 and Win8. It was be developed using Silverlight. In this time I need to develop the same application for Xbox 360.

So, I found a little information that Microsoft promised SL on Xbox (for example in link
http://www.engadget.com/2011/04/05/silverlight-coming-to-xbox-bringing-wp7-games-along-with-it/)

but I can't find any information about HOW I can develop application for Xbox using Silverlight.

Could someone show me a right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight SDK for Xbox hasn't been released yet (and I have no hope of coming soon) :-(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this website:
http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers
especialy at the bottom near Registered Developer Program and/or Tools and Middleware.

You need to get registered/licence with Microsoft to make apps for the Xbox360.
Im not sure if they let any random company make a App for their Xbox, but you can try.